# How should I reference a class in a definition file "*.d.ts" typescript while using external modules?

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have a class

```
export class Foo
{
   methodX():string
   {
   }
}

window.foo = new Foo();
```

and I have my window interface  what is the workaround to add Foo in window interface

```
interface Window {
    foo:Foo;
}
```

this is working for internal modules but not for external modules.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ambient interfaces in internal modules, so declare interface in separate file:

```
interface IFoo {
    methodX(): string;
}

interface Window {
    foo: IFoo;
}
```